# ASP.NET MVC - Custom client validation retrieving other property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

**What I am trying to accomplish**

So I have a viewmodel which contains an object that contains a list of Questions. I'd like to validate a property on the questions, where if another object (in this case a list) on the question is null, than the validation for that property should fail.

I have implemented the server side part of this and it works perfectly. The ObjectInstance is a Question and I can retrieve my other property from it.

However for the client side I don't have the object instance to work with. Instead I have the container and containertype. Easy right? They seem the same as the object instance so I can use those. Well the ContainerType is of type Question, but the Container itself is my ViewModel instance. This puts me at a loss. I've looked through the metadata and i've searched on the internet for hours but I can't find a way to retrieve my object instance.

**Question**

So my question is, how can I retrieve my object instance or can I validate my requirement in another way?

**IsValid method**

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        var field = containerType.GetProperty(_otherProperty);

        if (field != null)
        {
            var otherProperty = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);
            var option = Convert.ToString(value);
            if (otherProperty == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
```

**GetClientValidationRules method**

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        //var depProp =  metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(_otherProperty).GetValue(metadata.Container);
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("otherproperty", depProp);
        rule.ValidationType = "requiredifempty";
        yield return rule;
    }
```

**Custom jQuery validation**

```
if (jQuery.validator && jQuery.validator.unobtrusive) {
            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("requiredifempty", "otherproperty");

            jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredifempty", function (value, element, requiredifempty) {
                if (requiredifempty === null || requiredifempty === '') {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
```

Comment: A little unclear what your wanting to do. If the 'other property' is a collection, then you will not be able to get client side validation using jquery validate

Comment: The other property is indeed a collection but if it's possible for non-collection than i'd like to see that as well. My problem is retrieving the instance of the object that the property to be validated on resides in.

Comment: Your problem is with `jQuery.validator.addMethod("requiredifempty", function (value, element, requiredifempty)` - `requiredifempty` is the params  - i.e. the name of the other property (and it will never be `null` or empty. I assume your confused how it works so suggest you read [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: I would like to have my object instance beforehand in the getclientvalidationrules method. This way I can send my 'other property'  as a parameter to this jquery validation method and just check if it's null or anything else. It worked supplying it with hardcoded values.

Comment: Your 'otherproperty' needs to refer to an element in the DOM - see the section _CREATING A CUSTOM JQUERY VALIDATE FUNCTION_ in the link I gave you. You need to get the DOM element for the 'otherproperty' and make the comparison, but since you cannot create a single DOM element for a collection, it cannot work.

Comment: I don't want the name of the other property to be passed, I want the value of the other property to be passed. I want to retrieve the value in the getclientvalidationrules method and pass that as the parameter. I can let the isvalid method from the same class retrieve the value and id like to do the same in the getclientvalidationrulesmethod. That's the commented part that doesn't work since the container on the metadata isn't of the type question whereas the containertype on the metadata says the type is question.

Comment: Your still not understanding how jquery validation works. You CANT pass the value of the property. You pass the name of the other property. the script then finds the DOM element with the `id` that matched the name and gets the its value.

Comment: Very well you say it's impossible then maybe you can answer the second part of my question on whether I can do it in another way. Currently it's validating this requirement server side - which works fine other than that it's not very user friendly. All other elements on the page provide validation feedback before submitting the form while these ones don't until I submit the form and determine that the model state is invalid. I would like to validate the same thing on the client somehow.

Comment: You can always write your own script by handling the forms `.submit()` event. Do your custom validation and if not valid, cancel the submit and display an error message (add a `<span id="myerror" class'field-validation-error"></span>` to your form as a placeholder to display the message). Without knowing your model, which property your trying to validate, and what your rendering in the view its impossible to give you any further guidance.